# What is a possible mapping for two given sets?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Suppose I a set of integers $n=\{0,1,2,...,80\}$ and $m=\{0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,...\text{repeats from start}...\}$
where $|n|=|m|=81.$ What is a function that describes the mapping $n$ to $m$? I was able to get one if $m$ were to be $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,0,1,2,....,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,...\text{repeats from start}...\}$ using a couple of floor functions and mods but that is not what I am looking for.

Comment: An idea too vague for a hint. The structure of the data suggests that writing each element of $n$ as a three digit number in base $3$ will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you are looking for
$$f(k)=\begin{cases}
 2, & \left(\left\lfloor \frac{\left\lfloor \frac{k}{3}\right\rfloor }{3}\right\rfloor
   -2\right) \bmod 3=0 \\
 1, & \left(\left\lfloor \frac{k}{3}\right\rfloor -\left\lfloor \frac{\left\lfloor
   \frac{k}{3}\right\rfloor }{9}\right\rfloor \right) \bmod 2 \neq 0\\
 0, & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0):

"What is a function that maps n to m?"  Um,.... what you just said *was* a  function that maps $n$ to $m$.  Functions don't need algebraic formulas or rules.  Any mapping *IS* a function.

But if you want description:

Let $k  = 27a + 9b + 3c +d$ be the unique expression of $k$ as base three numbers.  That is $a,b,c,d \in \{0,1,2\}$.

$f(k) =\begin{cases}2&\text{if }b = 2\\1&\text{if }b\ne 2\text{ and }b+c\text{ is odd}\\0&b\ne 2\text{ and }b+c\text{ is even}\end{cases}$.

.....

I guess another way putting it is

$f(x) = 2$ if $[\frac{[\frac{[\frac x3]}3]}3]\equiv 2\pmod 3$

Otherwise $f(x) =1$ if $ [\frac x3]$ is odd.

Otherwise $f(x) = 0$.

where $[]$ is the greatest integer function.

Comment: Yes the edit was exactly was I looking for. Out of curiosity, how did u notice that such expression worked?

Comment: @fleablood I tested out the second formula in c++ but it does not work, suppose $n= 4$, we should get $m=4$, however your formula yields $m=0$. I unaccepted as I want to see if there are any other methods other than the first one you provided.

Comment: Hmmph... I went a level too deep.  That's all.

Comment: @fleablood There is still some issue with the formula as $n=18$ should yield $m=2$. Your formula sets $m=0$.